# How does Google Books detect unusual traffic from a computer?

Tags: google-books

From https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640

> You may see "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your
>   computer network" if Google detects that a computer or phone on your
>   network may be sending automated traffic to Google.
>
> Automated traffic includes:
>
> Sending searches from a robot, computer program, automated service, or
>   search scraper Using software that sends searches to Google to see how
>   a website or webpage ranks on Google

When this happens in Google Books, what are some possible criterions that Google Books or similar sites can use to  detect that a compute may be sending automated traffic to their sites?

Comment: Your IP address is probably the major criteria. Things like User-Agent, lack of cookies/session id, etc, are probably secondary criteria. Using torproject.org may help

Comment: @barrycarter, I doubt it. Tor exit nodes get blocked very quickly by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses complex [anomaly detection](https://www.google.com/patents/US8554703) systems, which are getting popularised with the [NoCaptcha ReCaptcha](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html).

Everything started with a [mere counting of accesses](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2010088550A2), of course. You can have fun looking for [more Google stuff](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=inassignee:google&num=10).